# Uncover labels in pgfplots with beamer

Tags: beamer, pgfplots

I would like to uncover the labels of the y axis of a plot made with package `pgfplots` in a presentation made with package `beamer`.  I tried several alternatives (`\alt`, `\only`, etc.) without success.  How this can be done?

A failed example follows, where all the labels appear together at a single tickmark in the second slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{semilogyaxis}[log basis y=10,
                          ytickten={2,...,6},
                          yticklabels={\alt<2>{a,b,c,d,e}{}}]
          \addplot[ybar,fill,color=green] coordinates {(-1,1e2)};
          \addplot[ybar,fill,color=red] coordinates {(1,1e6)};
     \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Jan provided the correct answer. In addition, here is an explanation of what is going wrong: `yticklabels` accepts a comma-separated list of labels - and `\alt<2>{...}{}` is considered to be a comma-separated list with exactly one entry. To reformulate your task by means of `yticklabels`, you would need a comma separated list of 4 entries of the form `\alt<2>{a}{},\alt<2>{b}{},...` (sorry, I missed Werners answer below)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `yticklabel` instead of `yticklabels`.  It takes a latex command that generates each label, instead of a list of labels.  See the [`pgfplots` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{semilogyaxis}[log basis y=10,
                          ytickten={2,...,6},
              yticklabel={$\visible<2>{\ifcase\ticknum\relax a\or b\or c\or d\or e \else d\fi}$}]
          \addplot[ybar,fill,color=green] coordinates {(-1,1e2)};
          \addplot[ybar,fill,color=red] coordinates {(1,1e6)};
     \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks strange that `\visible` works with `yticklabel` and not with `yticklabels`. Anyhow, I find this solution "cleaner".  Besides, `\visible` always occupies space, so `\phantom` is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an option. It is perhaps not ideal, but it works.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{pgfplots}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}[log basis y=10,
                       ytickten={2,...,6},
                       yticklabels={
                         \only<1>{\phantom{a}}\only<2>{a},
                         \only<1>{\phantom{b}}\only<2>{b},
                         \only<1>{\phantom{c}}\only<2>{c},
                         \only<1>{\phantom{d}}\only<2>{d},
                         \only<1>{\phantom{e}}\only<2>{e}}]
    \addplot[ybar,fill,color=green] coordinates {(-1,1e2)};
    \addplot[ybar,fill,color=red] coordinates {(1,1e6)};
  \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I guess the important thing is that the `tikzpicture` remains stationary from one slide to the next.

Comment: Ah, you are faster than me, I was trying a `foreach` loop for the generation.

Comment: Why not just ...`\only<2>{a},\only<2>{b}`...  It seems that the `tikzpicture` remains stationary even in this way.  I mean, `\phantom` seems unnecessary.

Comment: @ASdeL: If I have `\only<2>{a}`,`\only<2>{b}`,... the `tikzpicture` moves between slides. It may be that you only need one `\phantom` (the widest would work).

Comment: You are right, the `tikzpicture` moves in the example I posted.  However, in my original picture I have a `ylabel` in the `axis`.  If you add the `ylabel`, the picture does not move anymore.  Anyhow, perhaps it is safer to use `\phantom`.